# I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when trying to bind Text property of an Entry to an item in an array

Tags: .net, xaml, data-binding, maui

I am using MVVM Community Toolkit to create ObservableProperties in my ViewModel. One of those properties is a double[] array, that it is initialized in the constructor of the ViewModel.

Here is the view model:

```
public partial class LeñaViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ICalculatorService _calculatorService;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private DespachoLeñaModel _despacho;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private Cliente _cliente;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double _totalDespacho;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private double[] _test;

    static Page Page => Application.Current.MainPage;

    public LeñaViewModel(ICalculatorService calculatorService)
    {
        Title = "Despacho Leña";
        _calculatorService = calculatorService;
        Despacho = new DespachoLeñaModel();
        Cliente = new();
        Test = new double[8];
    }
}
```

And here is the page where I am trying to make the binding of the `Text` property of the entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="ForestalCasablancaApp.Pages.LeñaPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ForestalCasablancaApp.Controls"
    xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ForestalCasablancaApp.ViewModels"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    x:DataType="viewModel:LeñaViewModel">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="150, *">

        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            Source="lena_background.jpg" />

        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">

            <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto, Auto">
                <controls:ClientInfoCard Grid.Row="0" />
                <Border
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    HeightRequest="{OnIdiom Phone=312,
                                            Tablet=390}"
                    Style="{StaticResource PageSectionCard}">
                    <VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource PageSubtitle}" Text="Mediciones" />
                        <Grid
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Padding="10,0"
                            ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *, Auto, *"
                            RowDefinitions="Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto, Auto"
                            RowSpacing="8">

                            ...

                            <Label
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                Text="Altura 1: "
                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Border Style="{StaticResource EntryCellBorderStyle}" />
                                <Entry
                                    Style="{StaticResource NumericEntryStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding Test[0], FallbackValue='', Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </Grid>

                            ...

                        </Grid>
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Every time I delete the binding from the entry, the error goes away and the app works again

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is just the case as you said.

But you can define your variable as follows:

```
    [ObservableProperty]  
    private List<double> test;
```

And initialize it as follows:

```
   Test = new List<double>();
   Test.Add(101);
   Test.Add(102);
   Test.Add(103);
```

Usage example:

```
  <Entry Text="{Binding Test[0], Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this approach and it worked. However, I still do not understand why my FallbackValue property is not working. I even added the TargetNullValue property to the Text, but it still didn't work.

Comment: It failed because an exception was thrown. When an exception happens, the source code (or XAML) must be changed, to avoid the exception. This is different than Maui "not resolving" (not able to find) the binding target. The exception implies that `Test` itself is null, so `Test[0]` throws an exception. TargetNullValue property won't help here; that would only be used if `Test[0]` were null (which is not possible for a `double`). I am surprised that using an array resulted in that exception. If you want, make a new issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your clarification!